# Bypassing null return from data access methods with tuple?

Tags: c#, tuples, return-value, data-access-layer

I have this data access method that return the availability of a lot in our ERP:

```
public JDEItemLotAvailability GetLotAvailabilityF41021(string _lot)
        {
            JDEItemLotAvailability _retValue = new JDEItemLotAvailability();
            _retValue.Lot = _lot;
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(_ERPConfig.ConnectionString))
            {
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.CommandText =
                    "select max(lilotn) lilotn,max(trim(limcu)) limcu,max(lilocn) lilocn," +
                    "max(lipqoh/100) lipqoh,max(liitm) liitm,max(imlitm) imlitm," +
                    "max(concat(imdsc1,imdsc2)) as imdsc,max(imuom1 ) imuom1 " +
                    "from "+ _ERPConfig .AS400Library +".f41021" + " left outer join proddta.f4101 on liitm=imitm " +
                    "where lilotn = ?";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lilotn", _lot);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (rdr.HasRows)
                {
                    rdr.Read();
                    if (rdr["lilotn"] != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        _retValue.Code = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("imlitm"));
                        _retValue.ShortCode = (int)rdr.GetDecimal(rdr.GetOrdinal("liitm"));
                        _retValue.Description = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("imdsc"));
                        _retValue.PrimaryUnitCode = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("imuom1"));
                        _retValue.AvailableQuantity = (int)rdr.GetDecimal(rdr.GetOrdinal("lipqoh"));
                        _retValue.BranchPlant = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("limcu"));
                        _retValue.Location = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("lilocn"));
                    }
                }
            }
            return _retValue;
        }
```

In case the method doesnt have rows the lot that will be returned has only one data field filled. Thats the way i am checking on above bussiness layer if it was successfull or not.

I dont like it. Someone mentioned tuple as a solution.

I guess i will have my method return a `tuple<MyObject, bool>` for example ?

**Added info:** I would like to be able to return also an answer to "why the object is null?". I am thinking of returning a tuple of object and an ENUM specifying the reason.

**UPDATE:**

I think i am gonna go this route:

Return a NULL object reference from data access method and have the BLL method return a `tuple<Myobject,ENUMreason>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just returning null and checking if there is any data in the datalayer so that from any place you use it the behavior will be the same.

Comment: This is exactly what i want to debate on. Either returning a full null reference or returning a tuple with null object AND a ENUM result. I need to check also why is null in order to adjust my bussinees behavior...

Comment: If you need to know the reason for the null, you need a richer return type. Either a custom type containing `JDEItemLotAvailability` and some `ReasonEnum`, or `Tuple<JDEItemLotAvailability, ReasonEnum>` will do the job just fine. I guess you could use an output parameter too. Not much to debate on really.

Comment: Thinking about this a little more, to prevent a null reference from being returned (if that's desirable), your return type could be defined as a value type - i.e. a struct.

Comment: My opinion, either you check in BL that there is no data through a property of your return type or via some custom logic, or you return null is the same thing. Either way, you will have to check everywhere you call this method, if data is returned. Another approach would be to return an IEnumerable<itemType> which can be empty and then only check if there is something custom to do if there is no data.